# How do I split integers in a list?

Tags: python

So I may sound like a noob but I wan't to know how I can split integers in a list
however the list is kept in a variable where the user can input his own numbers
currently this is what I have 
Please spot if I have made any mistakes

```
num = []
item = input(str("Please enter a series of numbers separated by a space").split())
[int(digit) for digit in str(item)]
num.append(item)
print(num)

quit_program = input("Would you like to print the average out or quit the program?") 
#Type "average" for the average however if you want to quit then type in "quit"

if quit_program == "quit":
  quit()
elif quit_program == "average":
  sum(num)/len(num)
```

Comment: `[int(digit) for digit in str(item)]` does nothing. you have to assign it to `num`. ad it's wrong. It's `[int(digit) for digit in item]`

Comment: I'm still learning thanks

Comment: downvote isn't mine BTW.

Comment: Don't do `str(item)` in your comprehension. That makes a *string representation* of the list returned by `split`, which will then iterate over the characters in that string.

Comment: Your second line of code, it doesn't ask for input, it just literally evaluates your question as a string, well it does but it's so messed up. It doesn't work is my point.

Comment: Thanks lool I'm a noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you've got your split in the wrong place.  You want to split the input string, not your prompt.

```
>>> inp = raw_input("please enter a series of numbers separated by a space\n")
please enter a series of numbers separated by a space 
3 4 5
>>> nums = [ int(i) for i in inp.split()]
>>> nums
[3, 4, 5]
```

You're also going to want to use raw_input if you just want your input to be a space separated string (see here: http://www.python-course.eu/input.php).  Then you're going to want to assign that conversion to ints somewhere so that you can use it later for you averaging.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot mate this helped me :)

Comment: I don't know how to